# Why do I always get 0?

Tags: php

I send a request to `file.php` with an url like this: `file.php?number=2`

file.php:

```
$number = 0;
if (isset($_GET['number'])) {
    $temp_var = $_GET['number']; // 2
    if (ctype_digit($temp_var)) {
        $number = (int)$temp_var; // 2
    }
}   
print $number; // 0
```

As a response I get 0 (zero). Why?

Comment: Where is `$fid` defined?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ctype_digit($temp_var)`? Note the `r`

Comment: @Halcyon Changed the name of the variable

Comment: @Akshat Tripathi I changed the variable names when he wrote the question. Still get zero

Comment: If $_GET['number'] isn't set, you'll get zero. Are you certain it's been set?

Comment: @versalle88 but I find myself in an if

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with ctype_digit()

Check out this example

```
<?php

$numeric_string = '42';
$integer        = 42;

ctype_digit($numeric_string);  // true
ctype_digit($integer);         // false (ASCII 42 is the * character)

is_numeric($numeric_string);   // true
is_numeric($integer);          // true
?>
```

`ctype_digit($integer);         // false (ASCII 42 is the * character)` this happens also in your case, because 2 is the ASCII value for a different non-numeric character and the if() returns false in your case.

If you want to check if the string or digit is in fact an int, you should use [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

and your code will become:

```
$number = 0;
if (isset($_GET['number'])) {
    $temp_var = $_GET['number']; // 2
    if (is_numeric($temp_var)) {
        $number = (int)$temp_var; // 2
    }
}   
print $number; // 2
```

**NOTE FROM MANUAL ON [ctype_digit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php):**

*This function expects a string to be useful, so for example passing in an integer may not return the expected result. However, also note that HTML forms will result in numeric strings and not integers. See also the types section of the manual.*

*If an integer between -128 and 255 inclusive is provided, it is interpreted as the ASCII value of a single character (negative values have 256 added in order to allow characters in the Extended ASCII range). Any other integer is interpreted as a string containing the decimal digits of the integer.*

PLUS:

if someone **REALLY ABSOLUTELY MUST** use ctype_digit(), for safety reasons, you can use this:

`ctype_digit((string) $value);`

this way, you will ALLWAYS be sure that `$value` is a string, and if it's composed only of numeric characters, then ctype_digit will evaluate to true ;)

Comment: Perfect and correct answer. See the differences online: https://eval.in/230383 (cast as string => 2) and https://eval.in/230384 (cast as int => 0).

Comment: How does `$_GET["number"]` become an `int` though? Assuming the input is not overwritten. It explains what OP is seeing but it's making a non-trivial assumption.

Comment: @Halcyon if the variable is set as a int (with typecasting or by definition) then it will remain an int on its entire lifetime. then, ctype_digit will evaluate it as a non numeric character, and it will return false

Comment: so basically, everything starts from the declaration. However, ctype digit is not the way to go. is_numeric() gives a way better evaluation for strings AND numbers as well

Comment: Let me ask more directly: I assume that input from `$_GET` is always a string, how does it become an int?

Comment: maybe he did not use a input and he used something else like a direct link :-? I cannot be sure, this is something that only the OP can answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Were is `$fid` defined?

```
if (ctype_digit($fid)) {
```

Do you mean to say:

```
if (ctype_digit($temp_var)) {
```

You were passing wrong parameter, `$fid` which was undefined.`$fid` is not set so condition false and not going in to `if (ctype_digit($fid)) {}` so result shows you initially defined `$number`

That is the reason why, you were always getting `0`.

**EDIT**

My answer was based on the previous version of the question.

The question poster has changed the content of the question.

I think, its not our mistake if some body finds our answers irrelevant.

Comment: The question is changed. It was different content when I answered.

Comment: Just delete your answer in that case, it's irrelevant now.

Comment: still not the issue at hand :D this is NOT why he got false, even if the declaration was correct. Check my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$number = 0;
if (isset($_GET['number'])) {
  if (is_numeric($_GET['number'])) {
    $number = (int)$_GET['number'];
  }
}   
print $number;
```

Edited following answer above to use is_numeric - much better idea